# Read the contents of a webpage after a delay

Tags: ajax, html-content-extraction

Is there any way to read the contents of a webpage once it gets loaded completely. I have to read the prices from a site and need to store them in my database. But the prices in the site loads through ajax. As a result , I just get "Loading" instead of values. Is there any way to extract the contents once the file get loaded completely.

Waiting for reply...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you read the contents from the file that is requested by that site?

Comment: But what if they check the referral , which is exactly has made me helpless. So, I cant access that file as well. Is there any way to bypass that referral check ??